# Good practice for drawable resource scaling

Tags: android, image, performance, android-drawable

I am facing a problem with the size of the generated apk for my app...

I was wondering if there can be any issue if I use only the xxhdpi folder for my drawables... I know that there can be some problem with 9 patch drawable but I don't have any.

The system should take care for scaling down my images, right? Are there other effects that can be dangerous?

Comment: You should definitly not use only the xxhdpi for your drawable... Take a look at the doc http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

Comment: Ok, I read but, it doesn't explain why (or I didn't understand it)... can you please explain why shouldn't I use this technique?

Comment: You must know there are lots of diferent screen sizes with android smartphones. Two solutions : you only use the Drawable folder for all your drawable, be it images, selector, .. OR you use all the folder ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and let android pick the good ones to use with the current phone/tablet. Here i'm only talking about best practices, you can always do what you want ;) (the second choice is the best practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, system takes care for scaling, but scaling at runtime can affect your app's performance, especially when the scaling factor is not power of 2.
2. Normally scaling down a image wouldn't cause quality problems. however, it may produce a **minor** impact on image quality under **some** circumstances, here's a test:

   image in xxhdpi folder, left side is how it looks like on a Nexus 5 (xxhdpi), right side is how it looks like on a Nexus 4 (xhdpi).
   [image]
3. If image size is less than 4px, app may crash when scaling down.

Conclusion: if app size is more important than problems above, then you can put all images in xxhdpi folder, except the small ones.